# Expectation/Variance of piecewise function of random variables

Tags: random-variables, expectation, variance, piecewise-continuity

Suppose we have a discrete r.v $X$ where $P(X=0) = 0.3$ and $P(X=U)=0.7)$ where U ~ Uniform(1,51).

How do we calculate E(X) and Var(X)?

Intuitively I understand E(X) should be $0*0.2+E(U)*0.8$ but I'm struggling to see why this is true mathematically. I'm lost on the variance. Thanks!

Comment: If $P(X=0) = 0.3$ and $P(X=U)=0.7$, I would have thought $E(X)=0\times 0.3+E(U)\times 0.7$.  Similarly $E(X^2)=0\times 0.3+E(U^2)\times 0.7$

Comment: I assumed it would be more complicated than that. Thanks!

Comment: @Henry [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1281596/322065) seems to do something different for $E(Y_i^2)$?